# Need RE for Picking up only UPPERCASE set of words before end of line

Tags: regex

I wanted to create regex that will pick up set of UPPERCASE words (seperated by spaces) on a line.

For Eg.in this text

```
    TOPIC ONE
    Description of this topic, one CAPITAL word
    TOPIC NUMBER TWO
    Description of this topic two CAPITAL word
```

I need to pick only TOPIC ONE and TOPIC NUMBER TWO  but not the word CAPITAL.

I tried the following RE

```
    \b[A-Z]+\b
```

which is able to pick up CAPITAL WORDS individually

I also tried

```
    \b[A-Z]+\ \b
```

but it picks all except last UPPERCASE WORD.

I want to make sure that RE should only pick More than one word always.

Here is sample text to test:

```
    CHIEF COMPLAINT  Weakness inability to talk

    HISTORY OF THE PRESENT ILLNESS  This is a yearold
    AfricanAmerican male with a history of hypertension who was
    in his usual state of health

    FAMILY HISTORY  Unknown

    SOCIAL HISTORY  The patient lives 

    PHYSICAL EXAMINATION ON ADMISSION  During the five minute
    examination the patient became progressively less responsive
    and then vomited requiring intubation and paralytics during
    the examination
```

Comment: Your title *before end of line* is misleading as it seems, you want to match upper case in `CHIEF COMPLAINT  Weakness...`. You want to match uppercase at start of line, after any optional whitespace?

Comment: wanted to match Titles ending with : anywhere in the document. @bobblebubble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)+\b
\b[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]+)+\b
\b\p{Lu}+(?:\h+\p{Lu}+)+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BlG8vC/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb%5BA-Z%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5BA-Z%5D%2B)%2B%5Cb):

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters (`\p{Lu}` matches any Unicode uppercase letter)
- `(?:\s+[A-Z]+)+` - 1 or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (`[^\S\r\n]+`, `\h+`, `[\p{Zs}\t]+` will match 1 or more horizontal whitespaces)
  - `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: Thank You Wiktor. ```\b[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]+)+\b``` works quite great however still cannot capture all the titles. but surely a good starting point.

Comment: @AdityaVartak Add more test cases and I will show how to match them. The text in your question is [handled as expected](https://regex101.com/r/BlG8vC/2), I believe.

Comment: I also wanted to capture words like ```Medical History:``` ```Family history:``` etc. what changes can be done to this regex- ``` \b[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]+)+\b:``` to make sure that can be done.

Comment: @AdityaVartak Do you mean you want to get any words, even non-capitalized, if they are followed with a colon? What is the verbal rule? [Look here, BTW](https://regex101.com/r/ppdT4W/1), does it help?

Comment: I am testing regex on regexr.com (javascript). But in code, im using python package re for extraction

Comment: The regex ```  \b[A-Z]+(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]+)+\b: ``` is helping me extract all capital words like FAMILY HISTORY:  but i also want to extract words like ``` Family History: ``` and ``` Family history: ```

Comment: @AdityaVartak Sorry, you have modified the regex by adding `:` and in your question, there are no `:` in your sample data. If you plan to match any words before a colon starting with an uppercase word you may use `r'^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Za-z]+)+(?=:)'` or `r'\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Za-z]+)+(?=:)'` (Python raw string literals given)

Comment: Hey shall i share you the link on regexr.com with the data and target ,can you guide me to extract from there? Comments might not be able to properly convey what i have to tell. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201705/discussion-between-aditya-vartak-and-wiktor-stribizew).